# Best practices to reduce React Native Bridge calls

Tags: react-native

Is there any best practices that I can refer to reduce the React Native bridge calls ?

**Currently below is one of the finding :**

- Never do string concatenation in your JSX. It makes multiple bridge calls based on ur code and then flatten it in the Native side (tested in Android).

**Eg:** 
Wanted to concatenate Rating text with Rating symbol. So, I have written the below code.
[image: Code for the same]

Three bridge calls were happening :
[image: Bridge calls for single text]

Created the variable and assigned the same thing which I was doing inside JSX.
[image: Changed Code]
Now, there was single bridge call :
[image: Correct Bridge calls]